# How to change page title of a category programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, category, page-title

I am using magento 1.7 and i want to display the category title(meta title) as in the format of `[Sub-Sub-Category] - [Sub-Categories] | main category` for all sub-sub-categories.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to admin panel
2. Goto catalog-->manage categories
3. Select category which you want to change the title
4. Goto display options and enter there your desire page title
5. Save category
6. clear cache and refresh website frontend.

Comment: thank you for your answer.but it is a difficult solution and need to add title for every category.but i need it programmatically

Comment: If you think this is also useful through admin panel, please upvote bro. if i get the solution , sure i will post programmatically

Comment: if you are aware of this answer please post ..

Answer (score 0):

In this case,you need to change do some code.

First,you need call **an observer** on event *`core_block_abstract_to_html_before`*

And on `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` class update **your page title**

**config.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
......
    <models>
      <changecategorytitle>
        <class>Devamitbera_Changecategorytitle_Model</class>
      </changecategorytitle>
    </models>
......
  </global>
  <frontend>
    <events>
    <core_block_abstract_to_html_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>changecategorytitle/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>updatePageTitle</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    </events>    
  </frontend>
......
</config>
```

**Observer**

```
<?php
class Devamitbera_Changecategorytitle_Model_Observer
{

        public function updatePageTitle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
            $block = $observer->getBlock();

            if($block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head) {
                /* sub -sub category level always be  4 */
                if(Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current_category')->getLevel() > = 4){
                    $_category =  Mage::registry('current_category');   
                    $pathInStore = $_category->getPathInStore();
                    $categories = $_category->getParentCategories();
                    $pathIds = explode(',', $pathInStore);
                    $title =array();
                        foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
                            if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && $categories[$categoryId]->getName()) {
                                $title[$categoryId] =  $categories[$categoryId]->getName();
                            }
                    }
                    $block->setTitle(implode('-', $title));

                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: hi,this is not working

Comment: Have u create full module?

Comment: no.please describe detaily